# Поле ввода в спрятанном в кнопку меню теряет фокус сразу после получения

Tags: javascript, html

Есть реализация меню, спрятанного в кнопку. По задумке - отображается при нажатии на кнопку, скрывается при клике вне меню. Для упрощения реализовано было скрытие с небольшой задержкой после потери фокуса.

```
function iterateChildren(fromElement, whatToDoFunc){
    var child = fromElement.firstElementChild;
    while (child != null) {
        iterateChildren(child, whatToDoFunc);
        child = child.nextElementSibling;
    }
    whatToDoFunc(fromElement);
}

function showMenu(containerId) {
    var el = document.getElementById(containerId);
    var setVisible = function(element){
        if (element.tagName == 'A') element.style.display = 'inline';
        else
            if (element.tagName != 'SCRIPT' && element.tagName != 'STYLE') element.style.display = 'block';
        };
    iterateChildren(el, setVisible);
    el.focus();
}

function hideMenu(containerId) {
    var el = document.activeElement;
    var isDerivedFromMenu = 0;
    var elP = el.parentNode;
    while (elP != null)
    {
        if (elP.getAttribute('id')==containerId)
        {
            isDerivedFromMenu = 1;
            break;
        }
        if (elP.tagName == 'HTML') break;
        elP = elP.parentNode;
    }
    if (isDerivedFromMenu == 0)
        document.getElementById(containerId).style.display='none';
}
```

Пока в меню были только ссылки, подразумевающие одноразовое нажатие (нажатие с переходом) всё работало хорошо. Но теперь появилась необходимость в таком меню расположить форму входа на сайт.

Проблема заключалась в том, что при получении фокуса полем ввода фокус у контейнера меню теряется и срабатывает событие, его скрывающее (вместе с полем ввода, соответственно). Как решение было выбрано отключение события скрытия при получении фокуса элементом формы и его включение после потери фокуса элементом формы (с передачей фокуса обратно контейнеру меню).

```
function pauseHiding(hiderId) {
    var hider = document.getElementById(hiderId);
    hider.onblur = null;
}

function resumeHiding(hiderId, timeout) {
    var hider = document.getElementById(hiderId);
    hider.onblur = "setTimeout(function(){hideMenu(hiderId);}, timeout);";
    hider.focus();
}
```

---

Сейчас проблема в том, что при получении фокуса поле ввода сразу же его теряет (если не зажимать на нём мышью). Причём обрабатываются оба события, но контейнеру меню не возвращается обработчик события потери фокуса.

Выжимка вопроса:

- Почему поле ввода теряет фокус сразу после получения?
- Почему контейнеру меню не возвращается обработка события потери фокуса?
  И, соответственно, как с этим бороться.

  https://jsfiddle.net/2dxre6nz/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Почему поле ввода теряет фокус сразу после получения?

Добавьте вызовы `console.log()` в ваши функции и проверьте, соответствует ли ваше представление о том, когда они вызываются, реальности. Я не стал чинить ваш код, но похоже ваша проблема в ["event bubbling"](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow): когда вы жмете на `input` внутри `&lt;div>` срабатывает `onclick` на самом `div`, который выполняет `div.focus()`, отбирая фокус у `input`.

> Почему контейнеру меню не возвращается обработка события потери фокуса? И, соответственно, как с этим бороться.

Проще было бы ответить, если бы вы завершили процесс уменьшения примера до конца. Тогда бы вы пришли к тому, что вот такая конструкция установки обработчиков не работает:

```
hider.onblur = "setTimeout(function(){hideMenu(hiderId);}, timeout);";
```

Уменьшенный пример:

```
<div id="a">click me</div>
<script>document.getElementById("a").onclick="alert(1)";</script>
```

Тут дело в том, что `on*` в JS имеют тип функция, а не строчка. Когда вы в HTML пишете `<div onclick="код">`, div.onclick на самом деле равен `function(event) {код}`.

Но вообще зря вы стираете и возвращаете onblur, лучше сделайте флаг и проверяйте его в обработчике onblur.

> ---

По поводу исходной проблемы, мне вообще кажется сомнительной идея опираться на фокус (почему бы вам не отлавливать щелчки мимо меню и не закрывать его в этом случае?).

Если уж хотите фокус, я бы проверял при любом изменении фокуса (в [глобальном обработчике `focus`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28194767/1026)), что `document.activeElement` все еще находится внутри меню, а не как у вас сейчас - с кучей обработчиков на разных элементах, которые включаются и выключаются по ходу дела...